# Swift - why elements don't have equal sizes?

Tags: swift, xcode, view, uikit

I have a `Vertical Stack View` on my screen (`Alignment = Fill, Distribution = Fill`).

In it there are from top to bottom:

1. `Label` (no constraints)
2. `Vertical Stack View` (`height=21`)
3. `Horizontal Slider` (`height=21`)
4. `Label` (no constraints)

I was expecting that both my labels (elements 1 &4) will be of equal size and will occupy the majority of the screen and 2nd & 4th elements therefore would be in the center of the screen. But in reality my bottom Label's height is sufficient only to fill it's text while my top Label takes the majority of the space.

I tried to change the `Distribution` of my Stack View to `Fill Proportionally`, but in that case my top label becomes smaller than the bottom one.

Why is it happening? How can I make my Labels to become of equal height?

[image]

[image]

PS I noticed a warning about Content Priority Ambiguity but I can't figure out what should I do about it

[image]

Comment: The hugging priority is indeed the problem.

Comment: @matt , I read about hugging priority and compression resistance but there is a problem with another labels. These properties of my "EDIT TIMER" and "ANOTHER" labels are equal therefore I can't understand why they take different sizes.

Comment: Because they are equal. Without more information, the stack view does not know which view to stretch.  So it just picks one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make both labels equal in height I had to select both of them and add a constraint **Equal Heights**.
[image]

Warning about **Content Priority Ambiguity** was not about them, it was about horizontal labels. To remove warning while keeping their placement I changed **Distribution** of the horizontal **Stack View** to **Equal Centering**.